# Symfony Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a CollectionValuedAssociationField

Tags: list, symfony, filter, doctrine, query-builder

I'm using a query builder to set up a list of documents who have different relationships to other entities. The list also includes a filter form for all of the entities in that query builder.

It worked fine for all of them so far, but as soon as I added the $products entity, it doesn't work any more.

My code:

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
          $query = $qb->select('d', 'p')
          ->from('DocumentBundle:Document', 'd')
          ->innerJoin('d.products', 'p')
          ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
          ->join('d.type', 'dt')
          ->join('d.status', 's');


        if(count($type) > 0){
          $query->andwhere($query->expr()->in('d.type', ':type'))
            ->setParameter('type',$type);
          }
          if(count($status) > 0) {
              $query->andWhere($query->expr()->in('d.status', ':status'))
              ->setParameter('status', $status);
          }

          if(count($markets) > 0){
            $query->andWhere(':marketIds MEMBER OF d.markets')
              ->setParameter('marketIds',$markets);
            }
            else{
            $query->andWhere(':marketIds MEMBER OF d.markets')
              ->setParameter('marketIds',$userMarkets);
            }

          if(count($airlines) > 0){
            $query->andWhere(':airlineIds MEMBER OF d.airlines')
              ->setParameter('airlineIds',$airlines);
            }else{
            $query->andWhere(':airlineIds MEMBER OF d.airlines')
              ->setParameter('airlineIds',$userAirlines);
            }

          if(count($products) > 0){
            $query->andWhere(':productIds MEMBER OF p.id')
              ->setParameter('productIds',$products);
            }
          //   else{
          //   $query->andWhere(':productIds MEMBER OF p.id')
          //     ->setParameter('productIds',$currentuser->getProducts());
          //   }

          $query->andWhere('d.active = ?1')
                ->setParameter(1, $archive ? 0 : 1);
          return $query
            ->setFirstResult($page * $maxRows - $maxRows)
            ->setMaxResults($maxRows)
            ;
```

So for type and status, I have a ManyToOne relationship, for markets, airlines and (the troublemaker) products, it's a ManyToMany relationship.

The current code throws the exception:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 237 near 'id AND d.active': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. Must be a CollectionValuedAssociationField.

The strange thing about this, is that I have an other list for another entity which also has a ManyToMany relationship to products, and for that list it is working. Also strange about this: for that other list my query looks like that:

```
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb->select('a', 'p')
    ->from('AppBundle:Agency', 'a')
    ->innerJoin('a.products', 'p')
    ->orderBy('a.id', 'ASC');

    if(count($markets) > 0){
      $query->andWhere('a.market IN (:marketIds)')
        ->setParameter('marketIds',$markets);
      }
      else{
      $query->andWhere('a.market IN (:marketIds)')
        ->setParameter('marketIds',$currentUser->getMarkets());
      }

      if(count($products) > 0){
        $query->andWhere('p.id IN (:productIds)')
          ->setParameter('productIds',$products);
        }
        else{
        $query->andWhere('p.id IN (:productIds)')
          ->setParameter('productIds',$currentUser->getProducts());
        }
```

It's a ManyToOne for markets and a ManyToMany for products here.

I tried to user the same code (`p.id in (:productIds)`...) for my documents and this is kind of working, so I at least don't get an error any more. But when I then filter on something (like markets, airlines, products etc.) it's not working any more, so the list is just empty. Filtering for that second list is working though, so I don't know where this is coming from.

### Code update

```
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
          $query = $qb->select('d', 'p', 'm', 'a')
          ->from('DocumentBundle:Document', 'd')
          ->innerJoin('d.products', 'p')
          ->innerJoin('d.markets', 'm')
          ->innerJoin('d.airlines', 'a')
          ->orderBy('d.id', 'DESC')
          ->join('d.type', 'dt')
          ->join('d.status', 's');
  if(count($type) > 0){
          $query->andwhere($query->expr()->in('d.type', ':type'))
            ->setParameter('type',$type);
          }
          if(count($status) > 0) {
              $query->andWhere($query->expr()->in('d.status', ':status'))
              ->setParameter('status', $status);
          }
if(count($markets) > 0){
            $query->andWhere('m.id IN (:marketIds)')
              ->setParameter('marketIds',$markets);
            }
          if(count($airlines) > 0){
            $query->andWhere('a.id IN (:airlineIds)')
              ->setParameter('airlineIds',$airlines);
            }
            if(count($products) > 0){
              $query->andWhere('p.id IN (:productIds)')
                ->setParameter('productIds',$products);
              }
$query->andWhere('d.active = :archiveParam')
                ->setParameter("archiveParam", $archive ? 0 : 1);
                dump($query->getQuery());
```

Filtering is working for status, type and markets but not for airlines and products. Any ideas?

**Reproducing issue**

[image: Filter Form]

So this is my filterform (unnecessary filters are black). they are all multiselect dropdowns. When filtering for markets and status, the list is reducing to only the documents who have that certain status or are assigned to the selected markets. For all of the ManyToMany relationships(markets, airlines and products) I have own database tables and they all contain data.

Sample data would be:

Document Nr. 42 is assigned to airlines LH and LX, to markets CA, MX and US and to product Nr. 1. So when filtering for one of the markets, the document always appear in the list. But when filtering for one of the airlines or the product, the list stays empty.

### Edit

I just recently added the product filter and before I had that one, the filtering for airlines actually worked fine. Even though I used the 'wrong' query with MEMBER OF d.airlines.

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
if(count($products) > 0){
    $query->andWhere(':productIds MEMBER OF p.id')
        ->setParameter('productIds',$products);
}
```

should look like this

```
if(count($products) > 0){
    $query->andWhere('p.id IN (:productIds) ')
        ->setParameter('productIds',$products);
}
```

You are also mixing positional and named parameters.

```
$query->andWhere('d.active = :archiveParam')
    ->setParameter("archiveParam", $archive ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: Note: I said that I already tried that way but then the filtering wasn't working anymore.. Anyways I updated my code but it's still not working..

Comment: Note: My answer definitely fixes this error in your query. If you have other errors/questions - be more specific explaining them(or just read my comment next time).

Comment: why being so nasty?

Comment: I'd have to wait 90 minutes in order to post another question.. I would be really thankful if you could help me out here so that I can quickly fix my issue and as soon as i can post again, I will post the question and you can answer it there again? Would be really highly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I'll try to! just give me a minute :)